# Access private inner class, through a public outer class - from another class

Tags: java

I am completely stuck on this and have been playing around with it for a while. I have a class "launcher", from which I want to access an instance of a private inner class "PropertyInstance", through the outer class "PropertyManager".

So, in my launcher I would like to write:

```
        PropertyManager pm = new PropertyManager();
        PropertyInstance pi = pm.getInstance("brickbreaker.properties");
```

In my PropertyManager class I have written the following code:

```
public PropertyInstance getInstance(String location)
{
    PropertyInstance pi = null;

    if(!propertyList.contains(location))
    {
        System.out.println("it does not contain it yet, so we will create it");
        pi = new PropertyInstance(location);
        propertyList.add(pi);
    }

    return pi;
}
```

And inside this class, I have the following inner class:

```
private class PropertyInstance
{
}
```

Which is irrelevant apart from the private modifier.

The problem is that I can not access the PropertyInstance class from my Launcher due to it being private, and I do not seem able to find a workaround so really any help is appreciated. If it can even be done.

EDIT: It seems to be unclear that I'm looking for a workaround whilst keeping the inner class private, sorry for the confusion! :)

Comment: Make PropertyInstance public...

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to return a private class from a public method. Private means private. You don't make private things public.

Comment: @JBNizet: although bmargulies has a good answer to that.

Comment: Yes, but why make an interface if that private class is the only implementation. Making the class public is fine.

Comment: But why make it public if there is no need to? It reminds me of Swing's use of Graphics implementations. The implementations are hidden but the abstract classes are public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an interface that defines the public access you want to your private class, make your private class implement it, and return it as that.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to make it public.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. That's not what I want, I need a workaround whilst it being private, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: This is the whole purpose of private, to make it invisible for outer classes. So ... I don't really get it.

Comment: You may use reflection too to get to it btw.

Comment: I want to limit access to the class, so only one class can instantiate it, but others can use it. I think I might have just answered my own question by replying this :P

Comment: @DylanMeeus then make the constructor private. Not the class.

Comment: Although advising to use reflection is dubious, IMO.

Comment: "reflection... is dubious, IMO" -> I think it's possible but I consider it a hack in this case. OK, removed this.